# Why does System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir") return a read-only directory on Mac OS X Catalina 10.15

Tags: java, temporary-files, macos-catalina

This method used to return a writable directory until Mac OS X Mojave. Starting with Catalina.
Is there a way to add writability to the permissions of this temporary dir returned?

> ls -larth
>   /var/folders/qx/045nmsxx55575_gqycvvs1480000gp/T/1579829982927-0 total 16
>   drwxr-xr-x    4 me  staff   128B Jan 23 17:39 .
>   **drwx------@ 118 me  staff   3.7K Jan 23 17:39 ..**

Answer (score 2):

It IS writable; that line means it is a directory, and the directory's owner can write to it just fine (which, would be you, and by extension, all processes you invoke).

The problem with the old `/tmp` solution is that everyone and everything can write to it, so using it for just about anything is a security issue.